# How to mail a log file to yourself using PHP from a Windows machine ?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

### Situation:

- I run a PHP script from a windows 7 machine using CLI.
- My script will do its thing and then generate 1 log file at the end.
- I already got all that part working.

In addition to that, I want to **email** myself that log file every time the script runs.

Somewhere in the bottom of my script I tried this :

```
mail('email@gmail.com', 'Report', strip_tags($response). PHP_EOL );
```

The script run all the way to the bottom, I got my log file to generate, I also got a report on my CLI as well, but I **never** receive any email.

### Result :

[image]

I am not sure is because I :

- am on a Windows.
- need to allow specific php extension
- Need to configure more setting in my php.ini.

Can someone help clarify this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Mail Server which is configured in the `PHP.ini` to send your mails.

Here is a short Tutorial:

http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/05/31/sending-email-from-php-on-windows-using-iis.aspx

Note that the IIS6 console still needed for the Mail Server, also if you're hosting on >=IIS7.

Also you need to make sure, your Mail Server is acceptet by the Mail Server you want to send this mail to. This is definitve not a trival task. Gmail and GMX for example never accept it, if you didn't have `Reverse DNS` correctly configured.

If you don't know how, I highly recommend to have a talk to your System Administrator. Mail Server are very hard to setup correctly. It's a task I work around.

But here are the good news, if you do not want to configure your own mail server. It is very simple with an Hosted Email Adress and SMTP, if your using the Open Source Project [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer):

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

//More in the Documentation
```

It has a powerfull SMTP Class, which helps extreme for login into any SMTP Account (Gmail for example).

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer.

Comment: In order to use this line `require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';` Will I need to download anything ?

Comment: Yes you need to download it. I have linked it in the answer. Take a look here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Thanks. I am setting the configuration right now. Quick question ! what should I put in this line `$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');` ?

Comment: It is not required. If you set this up, you can set the Adress where an reply to this mail should be sended to (Example: You receive this Email in Outlook and click on Answer, the receipant would be `replyto@example.com<First Last>`

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks for the tip. Thanks for your time. Thanks for the whole thing.