# How to send emails in php

Tags: php, email

I have a php application I have running on my Xampp localhost. It has a user registration via email service, whereby a new user will register via email, but the account will not be active till activated by clicking on an email link sent to the email the user registered with.

I send email as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Sending email using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
   $to = "user@yahoo.com";
   $subject = "This is subject";
   $message = "This is simple text message.";
   $header = "From:user@GMail.com \r\n";
   $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
   if( $retval == true )  
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The email doesn't get sent. Is there something that I need to do before I can send email from a test website, or what is it I'm doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What does `$retval` return? What error messages are being shown? Need more information here. I would use something like http://swiftmailer.org/ instead.

Comment: use phpmailer which is good for mail service in PHP

Comment: Sending emails can be one of the most complex tasks you can do in programming these days. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/. Please try to research a little more into the topic and tell us in more detail how your system is set up and where exactly it seems to hang.

Comment: Which platform are you on? Sending emails via `mail()` is different between Windows and UNIX'y OS.

Comment: do you have any errors in your log?

Comment: none. No errors - @Wikunia

Comment: If you are on dev state, make sure you always set `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. Take a look in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28588957/2441442) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28905088/2441442), maybe this is the reason.